# Error Initializing Firepad

Tags: firebase, firepad

I am trying to use Firepad. While trying to use firepad I am getting below error.

In Firefox.

```
Error: i.parentNode is null
c@https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firepad/1.3.0/firepad.min.js:15:16104
c@https://cdn.firebase.com/libs/firepad/1.3.0/firepad.min.js:15:15380
```

In Chrome  I am getting below error.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'replaceChild' of null
at new c (firepad.min.js:15)
at Function.c (firepad.min.js:15)
at n.$scope.initFirepad (NotesUtils.js:231)


<div class="form-group">
<label for="inpNoteDescription" class="col-md-3 control-label">Note Description With Firepad</label>
<div class="col-sm-8" id="inpNoteDescription">
</div>
</div>
```

Kindly let me know if I need to do something else.

```
$scope.initFirepad = function(){
var firepadRef = $scope.initObj.firepadRef  ;        
var noteDescription = $scope.currentNote.description ;
var codeMirror = CodeMirror(document.getElementById('inpNoteDescription'), { lineWrapping: true });
var firepad = Firepad.fromCodeMirror(firepadRef, codeMirror, { richTextShortcuts: true, richTextToolbar: true, defaultText: noteDescription });
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34663494/how-can-i-make-add-firepad-to-my-reactjs-project ?

Comment: cross-posted: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/firepad-io/Rkpi9Y2opiM/IL-aOktjFQAJ